# Best practices coding c++

Tags: c++, function, status

I'm wondering, is there a better way to write code when there are functions with status returns.

Below is an example. (Please ignore simple code errors if there are any. I'm specifically talking about the structure. Plus, I'm at work and don't have a compiler on this computer)

```
#include "Session.h"

Session::Session(const char * IPaddress, unsigned int openPort)
{
    ssh_session mySession; 
    hostIP = IPaddress;
    port = openPort;
}

int Session::cBeginSession()
{
    try
    {
        int status = ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, &hostIP);
        if (status == 0)
        {
            status = ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY,                       
                                     SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL);
            if(status == 0)
            {
                status = ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
                if (status == 0)
                {
                    std::cout << "Session started\n";
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Unable to set port\n";
                    return -3;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Protocol option log verbosity unable to set\n";
                return -2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to set Host address\n";
            return -1;
        }
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        std::cout << "Unknown exception occurred\n";
        return -8;
    }
}
```

I typically use if-else statements with the status parameters, but I tend to end up with large nests of if-else statements if there are more than one or two functions involved. Is there a more readable way to write something like this? It turns into a rats nest very quickly.

**EDIT: Thank you for all the replies. I think I have some ideas of how to structure my code better. I appreciate all the diligent suggestions.**

Comment: I think exceptions are best in general. But make sure your code is [exception safe](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Comment: It's stronger than "i think". Exceptions are *the* recommended and standard way to communicate a failure when an operation is expected to succeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern C++ programming, typically, if you encounter an error where the program can't continue, then I think it's better to `throw` an exception.

So your function would wouldn't return anything (i.e. void).  Whenever it ran into a can't continue situation, you would `throw` an exception that tells what the error is.  The calling code would then deal with the error.

The advantage to this, is that you get to choose **where** to deal with the error.  For example, the stack may unwind all the up to `main`.

You code could look like this:

```
void Session::cBeginSession()
{
    if (ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, &hostIP))
    {
        // throw an exception
    }
    if (ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL))
    {
        // throw an exception
    }
    if (ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port))
    {
        // throw an exception
    }
}
```

Once you get the hang of coding with exceptions, code tends to be cleaner and more robust since you're not always worrying about checking return codes.

**EDIT**

To answer you comment.  You can choose how and when to handle the error.  You can just catch the exception above your call.  But, in general, if you want to do something that can fail (but not end a program) you can make another function that returns a boolean status.

`bool Session::tryCBeginSession()`

Now, your original function `void Session::cBeginSession()` would be implemented in terms of this new function.  I've found that in most cases writing these dual functions is done only in a limited number of cases.

Comment: "where the program can't continue" is a too narrow set of cases. There are many other.

Comment: Perhaps, but for that narrow case, surely exceptions are a good choice.

Comment: This seems to be the most readable of all the responses so far. One thing I've read is that using the catch portion of try-catch to redirect code is bad practice. Are there any thoughts on this? I'm interested in how I might recover and try again, or move on if something fails. I'd prefer that the program not just give up and exit.

Comment: Even without resorting to exceptions the OP's code would read a lot better  if it was coded with this style rather than resorting to nested if statements.

Comment: @justthom8 I've edited my answer to answer your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I like to reduce nesting, like this:

```
status = fcn1();
if ( status == 0 )
{
    //  something good
    status = fcn2();
}
else
{
    //  something bad happened.  report, and leave status reporting failure.
}

if ( status == 0 )
{
    //  something good
    status = fcn3();
}
else
{
    //  something bad happened.  report, and leave status reporting failure.
}

if ( status == 0 )
{
    //  something good
    status = fcn4();
}
else
{
    //  something bad happened.  report, and leave status reporting failure.
}
```

I like that error printing is close to the error occurrence.  Sure, when failure happens, the `status` gets checked extra times.  But it's a small price to pay for the simplicity.

This also lends itself well to de-allocation of resources and closing files at the end, regardless of where the error occurs.

Comment: This looks more like C than C++.

Comment: You are right.  I was only showing a "structure"/technique that is not limited to either C or C++.  While throwing an exception is the heart of the accepted answer and specific to C++, the usefulness is somewhat limited.  Every caller of this method must handle and report (probably text) independently.  With many callers, that's a bit of a downside.  Much depends on how the method is meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

- You don't need `if-else` if you either `return` or `throw` in the statement that follows (this is a good case for `throw`ing BTW). Plain `if`s will do.
- The type of messages you're printing are usually better suited to `stderr` rather than `stdout` (`cerr` rather than `cout`).
- If you decide you will keep using error statuses, symbolic constants (or enums or defines) are usually preferred over "magic numbers"

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty ideal scenario for exception-handling (at least how it was intended). Exception-handling is typically appropriate for handling external input errors, as in this case where the external input is coming from a socket.

You already have a try/catch block, but I would suggest eliminating it since there's no recovery code. Keep your `try`/`catch` blocks generally focused around areas where you make a change transaction. Catching an exception then rolls back the changes, gets the system back to a valid state, and possibly outputs some message.

Something like this:

```
 void Session::cBeginSession()
{
    if (ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, &hostIP) != 0)
        throw runtime_error("Unable to set Host address");

    if (ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL) != 0)
        throw runtime_error("Protocol option log verbosity unable to set.");

    if (ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port) != 0)
        throw runtime_error("Unable to set port");
    std::cout << "Session started\n";
}
```

Let the client code calling this function catch the exception at a site where it's appropriate to handle and recover from the error. Just worry here about throwing the exception appropriately in the case of these external input errors.

Note that exception-handling is typically ultra cheap in the non-exceptional cases (where you don't throw) with optimizations like zero-cost EH. However, these kinds of exception-handling compiler optimizations make the rare case much slower where you actually do throw an exception. So exceptions should be used for truly exceptional cases resulting from some kind of external input your software can't normally handle, as in this case.

Another caveat relevant in certain types of larger systems (plugin architectures, e.g.), is that typically exceptions should not be thrown across module boundaries.

This is somewhat opinionated but I don't recommend having lots of catch branches based on the type of exception (as commonly found in Java, e.g.). Often there isn't a need to distinguish the actual type of an exception so much as relay a message to the user, e.g. Catch exceptions as generally/coarsely as you can, and keep the `try/catch` blocks to a minimum (high-level transaction-oriented mentality: transactions succeed as a whole or fail and roll back as a whole).

Otherwise exceptions can really simplify these kinds of cases, and a whole lot of the C++ library (and even parts of the language) throw exceptions normally (I really think C++ and exception-handling are inseparably tied), so it can be useful to make use of them since a robust program will typically need to generally catch them anyway.

Comment: Your use of `!= 0` is akin to testing if a boolean value == true.

Comment: `operator!` would be my preference here if it's just 1/0, though I wanted to kind of try a more direct translation of op's original code. He seemed to prefer using `== 0`, and that convention seems kind of common in error-handling C code like this for some reason -- though I really like the terse form.

Comment: Oh well, I updated it with `operator!`!

Comment: Yeah, straight logic is easier for me to think through vs taking the opposite of whatever is there. It takes longer to read through code for me when nots abound everywhere.

Comment: I think you just broke the code.  No soup for you!

Comment: One thing I'm wondering though, is the cost of putting the function in the if statement. Once this gets put into assembly, where there be more cost or less? It's certainly far more readable than what I have in my first attempt. I'm curious if it will cost less/more, or hardly be noticeable. (Especially for a larger system)

Comment: @PeterM Doh -- I ended up looking up this ssh lib. My bad -- got the success/fail backwards.

Comment: Hmm -- given that it's got this kind of 0 on success, -1 on failure, I think the original way of just checking for inequality with 0 is still a bit clearer. I'm typically tempted to use the expression `x` or `!x` in boolean(true is non-zero)/pointer cases only. At least I avoid those mistakes that way. :-D

Comment: @justthom8 At least conceptually and purportedly in a zero-cost exception-handling system (which is a lot of what modern compilers implement these days), this avoids the cost of if/else kind of branching to propagate an error (though in this case, since `libssh` uses error-handling, we still have to pay a branching cost when directly calling its functions, but the difference is that we don't in those calling `cBeginSession`).

Comment: @justthom8 So, at least supposedly, this goes faster than putting a lot of `if (error_happened) return` kind of statements propagating errors down the call stack. Where zero-cost EH is really expensive is when you `throw`. There it's much slower -- but if it's an exceptional case, you typically shouldn't be worried about bottlenecks -- only the common case. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gnat_ugn_unw/Exception-Handling-Control.html

Comment: So compared to a bunch of `if error happened exit the function` kind of code, zero-cost EH (assuming your compiler implements it) makes the common case execution faster, but the exceptional code branch slower. The `if error return` kind of approach makes the common case potentially slower, but the rare error case faster.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case (error codes handling), I'm advocating for early returns:

```
int status = ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, &hostIP);
if (status != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Unable to set Host address\n";
    return -1;
}

status = ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY,                       
                         SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL);
if (status != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Protocol option log verbosity unable to set\n";
    return -2;
}

status = ssh_options_set(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
if (status != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Unable to set port\n";
    return -3;
}

std::cout << "Session started\n";
return 0;
```

I find the code much more readable because it has lest nesting and the error handling is kept close to the point where the error occured instead of being buried in a far else branch.

If you decide it is best to use exceptions rather than error codes, you can keep the same structure and replace returns with throws.

Comment: That is my preference, too, as long as clean up is simple.

Comment: Why not make it even more compact and assign `status` within the `if`statements?  Actually I take that back.  Your use of `status` is superfluous.

Comment: @PeterM Which would make it less readable/maintainable, too (besides the warning a compiler might issue)

Comment: @DieterLücking we are talking C++ here .. lol.  But using int's in if's should not cause a problem

Answer (score 0):

some suggestions noted in the code:

```
// improvement - derive your own descriptive exception FROM A STANDARD EXCEPTION TYPE
struct session_error : std::runtime_error
{
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

// improvement in constructor: initialiser lists
Session::Session(const char * IPaddress, unsigned int openPort)
: mySession()
, hostIP(IPaddress)
, port(openPort)
{
}

namespace {
    // use of anonymous namespace so this wrapper function does not pollute other compilation units
    void setopt(ssh_session& session, int opt, const void* val, const char* context)
    {
        if (ssh_options_set(session, opt, val))
            throw session_error(context);
    }

}

void Session::cBeginSession()
{
    // improvement - defer to wrapper function that handles nasty return code logic
    // and throws a sensible exception. Now your function is readable and succinct.

    setopt(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, &hostIP, "setting host option");
    setopt(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL, "setting verbosity");
    setopt(mySession, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port, "can't set port");

    std::cout << "Session started\n";
}
```

Comment: At first look, I would think this is quite a bit of extra work, and overdesign, vs simply using the function in an if-statement and calling the exceptions right after. I wouldn't expect the exceptions generated to change, only be added too. Am I wrong? I obviously don't have a lot of experience designing classes, so I could very well be missing some very good reasons to do such things.

Comment: depends how you measure work. it's fewer lines of code than the original, more succinct, the function now fits on one page and the method reports errors with an exception, relieving the caller of the burden of checking that the function succeeded. It's simply a fact that a developer will spend at least 10 times as long debugging a program than writing it. If you write it with that number in mind, you'll split logic into smaller units.

Comment: I feel like relieving the user of the status checking could be bad. That actually means you have to simply trust that everything went a'okay in the function call. I've written a lot of automated tests in matlab using third party funcionality, and I remember always being quite peeved when I had no way to know if the function returned okay. Other than that portion, I see your point.

Comment: you don't have to trust anything. If everything went a-ok there will be no exception. If it didn't, you'll get an exception to handle (or pass on up the call stack). This is fundamental to good c++ design.